# What would be the ideal way to do paging using a Infragistics WebDataGrid and SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, paging, infragistics

We have an application that is growing in users and the infragistics WebDataGrid and stored procedure are having performance issues.  I'm looking into adding the ROW_NUMBER() function in the stored procedure, but I'm concerned with sorting.  It looks like I would need to do change the procedure to have a dynamic order by case statement if I used the ROW_NUMBER function.  Are there any better options?

Comment: are you asking regarding creating an identity column as ROW_Number() ?

Comment: Yes, here is what I was thinking [Server-side paging with Row_number function](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2010/08/06/sql-server-2005-server-side-paging-with-row-number-function.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ExploringBeyondRelational+%28Exploring+Beyond+Relational+.......%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do paging - "The WebDataGrid™ control’s paging mechanism breaks data into pages reducing load time and increasing performance. The number of pages is determined by the page size and the total number of records from the data source. WebDataGrid retrieves new data for each page as your end-users navigate from page to page. Data is retrieved asynchronously by default, using AJAX."  and when sorting to sort the datasourse and then rebind the grid